# C# MediatR: Return nested/compound DTO

Tags: c#, automapper, dto, cqrs, mediatr

I want to return a compound/nested DTO `SearchDto` which includes `Status(timeMs, resultsFound)` and `List<SearchResult>`.

### Example JSON DTO

```
{
status: {
        timeMs: 0.038583,
        found: 728,
    },
    results: [
        {
            id: "c00f9c89-0683-4818-9043-0df10704f7dc",
            score: "32.03388",
            fields: {
                id: "f42d2a0d-3a30-4cb6-940f-fb474b82588b",
                type: "client",
                title: "Business Pty Ltd",
                description: "Client from Australia",
                status: "Active",
                url: "#client/f42d2a0d-3a30-4cb6-940f-fb474b82588b"
            }
        }
]}
```

### SearchDto.cs

```
    // The Search Result Data Transfer Object
    public record SearchDto(SearchStatusDto status, IEnumerable<SearchResultDto> results);

    // Status contains metadata about the search
    public record SearchStatusDto(double timeMs, int found);

    // Each Search Result has a unique ID and relevancy score; then contains the payload containing the result
    public record SearchResultDto(Guid id, double score, SearchResultFieldsDto fields);

    // Actual search data that gets displayed
    public record SearchResultFieldsDto(Guid id, string type, string title, string description, string status, string url);
```

### GetSearchResultsQueryHandler.cs

```
public async Task<SearchDto> Handle(GetSearchResultsQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Getsome data from the Search Results Entity.
            var items = await context.SearchResult.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
            // Map it to the Search Result Dto.
            var results = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<SearchResultDto>>(items);
            // Create the status object with example data.
            var SearchStatusDto status = new SearchStatusDto(0.00383, 500);
            // Amalgamate the status and List<Result> and return. (not implemented)
            return results;
        }
```

### Problem

The problem that I am running into is:

`The name 'status' does not exist in the current context [OrganisationName.Services.Api]csharp(CS0103)`

I'm pretty new to C#, .Net, and MediatR, so I"m not sure if I'm even approaching the problem correctly. Is it even possible/advisable to use MediatR like this?

Comment: `var object status`? Which is it?

Comment: My apologies, I was just experimenting to see if that would work. It should be `var SearchStatusDto status`.

Comment: what is producing the error? Don't think it's coming from any of the code you've given us

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'm pretty new to C# and didn't realise I needed to build the object using the `new` keyword then return it.

I fixed it using this code:
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/70764258/2334389

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to construct the `SearchDto` before returning it.

```
public async Task<SearchDto> Handle(GetSearchResultsQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var items = await context.People.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
    var results = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<SearchResultDto>>(items);
    return new SearchDto(
        new SearchStatusDto(0.03838, 300),
        results
    );
}
```